# Connected set in $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: general-topology

Let $$S:= \left\{\left(x, \sin\frac{1}{x}\right) \bigm\vert 0<x\le 1\right\}$$ denote a subset of the plane. Since $S$ is the image of the connected set $(0,1]$ under a continuous map, $S$ is connected. The only subsets of $S$ which are open and closed in $S$ are empty set and $S$ itself. 
 Then $\overline{S}$ is the closure of $S$. I can't understand here:
$\overline{S}$ equals the union of $S$ and the vertical interval $\{0\}\times[-1,1]$. But the vertical line $\{0\}\times[-1,1]$ which is the set of limit points of $S$ are not included in $S$. It contradicts that $S$ is equal to its closure.

Comment: Its quite hard to read your question, can you have a look at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to make it easier to read?

Comment: $S$ is equal to its closure as a subset of $S$, but not as a subset of $\Bbb R^2$. The closure of $S$ in $\Bbb R^2$ is the union of $S$ and the vertical line segment. There is no contradiction. Do you have a question? There is no question mark anywhere in your post.

Comment: The closure of a set $S$ is not an intrinsic property of  $S$. It depends on the topology of the space that $S$ is a subset of.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting:

> The only subsets of $S$ which are open and closed **in $S$** are the empty set and $S$ itself.

Note that it says "in $S$"; it does NOT claim that the set $S$ is closed in $\Bbb R^2$, which is false (as you so correctly observe). (To see that $S$ is closed in $S$, consider its complement in $S$...which is the empty set; that's open (in $S$, or anywhere else!), hence $S$ is closed in $S$.)

In short, there's no contradiction here, just a mis-reading.